# Relative motion and electricity

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-fields, electricity

Imagine you are in a bus moving with constant velocity (dv/dt=0). There is a charged particle outside the bus (on the road) at rest with respect to earth .

But with respect to you the charged particle is moving with same velocity as that of bus but in opposite direction
i.e current .

Isn't it a current without potential difference?

Also , we know that moving charge creates magnetic field. So if you hold magnet in your hand outside the window of the bus , will you experience any force ?

**Note**:- pls provide detailed answer and avoid giving answers in comment

Comment: There is nothing in the textbooks that requires a potential difference to have a current. Besides that you will, of course, see a potential difference when you are moving relative to a charge. The potential will change continuously. The precise way in which the electromagnetic field transforms under motion is described by special relativity.

Comment: (a) "Isn't it a current without potential difference?" There's no fundamental principle requiring a potential difference (pd). You do need a pd to sustain a steady current in a conductor (e.g. a metal wire), but a charged particle doesn't need a pd in order to keep travelling at a constant speed in a vacuum. (b) The moving charge will indeed set up a magnetic field as well as an electric field.

Comment: Pls provide detailed answer

Comment: If you want more detail for (a), I recommend that you consult a textbook about electrical conduction in a metal; the basic idea is that the free electrons encounter resistance to their motion and need an electric field to provide an opposing force so that they can move at a constant mean speed. As for (b) – the magnetic effect – It's difficult to go into more detail without more advanced Physics. You might care to look at answers to the question 'Magnetic force between 2 moving charges', but this may not be the sort of thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't it a current without potential difference?

Yes. There is no requirement that a current must be accompanied by a potential difference. It is common for people, after learning Ohm’s law, to think that it is mandatory, but it is not. There are even cases where you have a potential difference in the opposite direction of the current flow.

> Also , we know that moving charge creates magnetic field. So if you hold magnetic in your hand outside the window of the bus , will you experience any force?

Yes. There is indeed a magnetic field in the bus frame and a force will be exerted on a magnet just the same as if you were on the ground and a charge was attached to a different bus moving at the same speed in the opposite direction.